# Возникает ошибка при попытке получить длину списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Я задаю переменной `e` значение `['5+7']`, а `i` `0`

```
e = ['5+7']
i = 0
```

Затем я делаю цикл и использую `len(e)`

```
while i != len(e):
```

И получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Я использую **PyCharm Community Edition** (Python 3.8)

Если что, то ошибка в строке с `while i != len(e):`

Полный текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sysroot/home/user/PycharmProjects/E/main.py", line 282, in <module>
    compile_file("/sysroot/home/user/e/main.e")  # Replace compile_file to ask_path and remove function argument
  File "/sysroot/home/user/PycharmProjects/E/main.py", line 68, in compile_file
    main(code)
  File "/sysroot/home/user/PycharmProjects/E/main.py", line 215, in main
    parser(lexer(code))
  File "/sysroot/home/user/PycharmProjects/E/main.py", line 236, in lexer
    solve(replac("\t", "", replac(" ", "", replac("}", "", replac("{", "", find(r"\{.*?\}", code))))))
  File "/sysroot/home/user/PycharmProjects/E/main.py", line 79, in solve
    while i != len(e):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Вот весь код: [Ссылка на Google Диск](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vh0HXdx81e6KnG2AY2hrBIuMych5t9XK/view?usp=sharing)

```
from sys import exit as stop
from os import system, name
from colorama import Fore
import re

variables = {}

def crit(pre, text, line = -1):
    if line != -1:
        print(f"{Fore.RED}[{pre}] Строка {line}: {text}{Fore.RESET}")
    else:
        print(f"{Fore.RED}[{pre}] {text}{Fore.RESET}")
    stop()

def err(pre, text):
    print(f"{Fore.RED}[{pre}] {text}{Fore.RESET}")

prefix = "E"

def find(pattern, text):
    res = []
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, text, re.S):
        res.append(match.group())
    return res

def to_repl(what, to, where):
    i = len(what) - 1
    while i != -1:
        try:
            where = where.replace(what[i], to)
        except AttributeError:
            to_repl(what[i], to, where)
        i -= 1
    return where

def replac(what, to, where):
    i = len(where) - 1
    while i != -1:
        try:
            where[i] = where[i].replace(what, to)
        except AttributeError:
            replac(what, to, where[i])
        i -= 1
    return where

def ask_path():
    input("Введите путь к файлу: ").strip()
    try:
        f = open(path, 'r')
        code = f.read()
        f.close()
        clear()
        main(code)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        err(prefix, "Файл не найден")
        ask_path()
    except IsADirectoryError:
        err(prefix, "Указан путь к директории")
        ask_path()

def compile_file(path):
    path = path.strip()
    try:
        f = open(path, 'r')
        code = f.read()
        f.close()
        clear()
        main(code)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        err(prefix, "Файл не найден")
        ask_path()
    except IsADirectoryError:
        err(prefix, "Указан путь к директории")
        ask_path()

def solve(e):
    i = 0
    print(e)
    while i != len(e):
        e = solve_num(e[i])
        i += 1

def solve_num(num):
    rounds = num.count('*') + num.count('/') + num.count('+') + num.count('-')
    i = 0
    # Lexer только для цифр. Тут же всё и будет решаться и это будет возращать готовое значение
    # Если Lexer встречает умножение, или деление, то он выполняет это действие, изменяет num и алгоритм выполняется ещё раз

    while rounds != 0:
        num = solve_plus_minus(solve_mult_split(num))
        rounds -= 1

def solve_mult_split(num):
    mults = False
    splts = False
    num1 = ""
    num2 = ""
    stopped = False
    pt = False
    i = 0
    while i != len(num) and not stopped:
        if num[i] == '*':
            mults = True
            stopped = True
        elif num[i] == '/':
            splts = True
            stopped = True
        elif num[i] == '-' or num[i] == '+':
            num1 = ""
        else:
            num1 += num[i]
        i += 1
    i = 0
    stopped = False

    while i != len(num) and not stopped:
        if not pt:
            if mults:
                if num[i] == '*':
                    pt = True
            elif splts:
                if num[i] == '/':
                    pt = True
        else:
            if num[i] == '+' or num[i] == '-' or num[i] == '/' or num[i] == '*':
                stopped = True
            else:
                num2 += num[i]
        i += 1

    print(f"[E] Умножение/деление: Число 1: {num1}. Число 2: {num2}")
    if mults:
        return num1 * num2
    elif splts:
        return num1 / num2
    else:
        return num

def solve_plus_minus(num):
    pluss = False
    minss = False
    num1 = ""
    num2 = ""
    stopped = False
    pt = False
    i = 0
    while i != len(num) and not stopped:
        if num[i] == '+':
            pluss = True
            stopped = True
        elif num[i] == '-':
            minss = True
            stopped = True
        i += 1
    i = 0
    stopped = False

    while i != len(num) and not stopped:
        if not pt:
            if pluss:
                if num[i] == '+':
                    pt = True
            elif minss:
                if num[i] == '-':
                    pt = True
        else:
            if num[i] == '+' or num[i] == '-' or num[i] == '/' or num[i] == '*':
                stopped = True
            else:
                num2 += num[i]
        i += 1

    print(f"[E] Сложение/вычитание: Число 1: {num1}. Число 2: {num2}")
    if pluss:
        return num1 + num2
    elif minss:
        return num1 - num2
    else:
        return num

def clear():
    _ = system('cls' if name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def sub(ptrn, repl, arr):
    i = len(arr) - 1
    while i != -1:
        try:
            arr[i] = re.sub(ptrn, repl, arr[i])
        except AttributeError:
            sub(ptrn, repl, arr[i])
        i -= 1
    return arr

def fsplit(arr, spl):
    i = len(arr) - 1
    while i != -1:
        try:
            arr[i] = arr[i].split(spl)
        except AttributeError:
            fsplit(arr[i], spl)
        i -= 1
    return arr

def trim(arr):
    i = len(arr) - 1
    while i != -1:
        try:
            arr[i] = arr[i].strip()
        except AttributeError:
            trim(arr[i])
        i -= 1
    return arr

def main(code):
    parser(lexer(code))

def cut(string):
    return string.replace("'", "").replace('"', '').strip()

def parser(tokens):
    z = 0
    while len(tokens) > z:
        if tokens[z][0] == "print":
            print(tokens[z][1])
        elif tokens[z][0] == "error":
            crit(tokens[z][2], tokens[z][1])
        elif tokens[z][0] == "clear":
            clear()
        elif tokens[z][0] == "var":
            variables[tokens[z][1]] = tokens[z][2]
        z += 1

def lexer(code):
    code = to_repl(find(r">>.*?<<", code), "", code)
    code = to_repl(find(r">.*?\n", code), "", code)
    solve(replac("\t", "", replac(" ", "", replac("}", "", replac("{", "", find(r"\{.*?\}", code))))))
    lin = 1
    o = len(code.split("'")) - 1
    d = len(code.split('"')) - 1
    if o % 2 != 0:
        crit(prefix, f"Непарное количество кавычек (' = {o})")
    if d % 2 != 0:
        crit(prefix, f'Непарное количество кавычек (" = {d})')
    p = trim(fsplit(code.split("\n"), ":"))
    r = []
    i = 0
    while i != len(p):
        r.append([])
        if p[i][0] == "print" or p[i][0] == "error" or p[i][0] == "clear" or p[i][0] == "var":
            r[i].append(cut(p[i][0]))
            if p[i][0] == "print":
                args = trim(re.sub(r',(?=([^(\"|\')]*(\"|\')[^(\"|\')]*(\"|\'))*(?![^(\"|\')]*(\"|\')))', 'e_special_char_ᅠ0', p[i][1]).split("e_special_char_ᅠ0"))
                if len(args) == 1:
                    r[i].append(cut(args[0]))
                else:
                    crit(prefix, "Неправильное количество аргументов (ожидался 1 аргумент)", lin)
            elif p[i][0] == "error":
                args = trim(re.sub(r',(?=([^(\"|\')]*(\"|\')[^(\"|\')]*(\"|\'))*(?![^(\"|\')]*(\"|\')))', 'e_special_char_ᅠ0', p[i][1]).split("e_special_char_ᅠ0"))
                if len(args) == 2:
                    r[i].append(cut(args[0]))
                    r[i].append(cut(args[1]))
                else:
                    crit(prefix, "Неправильное количество аргументов (ожидалось 2 аргумента)", lin)
            elif p[i][0] == "clear":
                if trim(code.split("\n"))[i] != "clear":
                    crit(prefix, "Заданы аргументы (не ожидалось аргументов)")
            elif p[i][0] == "var":
                args = trim(re.sub(r',(?=([^(\"|\')]*(\"|\')[^(\"|\')]*(\"|\'))*(?![^(\"|\')]*(\"|\')))', 'e_special_char_ᅠ0', p[i][1]).split("e_special_char_ᅠ0"))
                if len(args) == 2:
                    r[i].append(cut(args[0]))
                    r[i].append(cut(args[1]))
                else:
                    crit(prefix, "Неправильное количество аргументов (ожидалось 2 аргумента)", lin)
            lin += 1
        elif p[i][0] == "":
            lin += 1
        else:
            crit(prefix, f"Неизвестное кодовое слово: {p[i][0]}", lin)
        i += 1
    return list(filter(None, r))

compile_file("/sysroot/home/user/e/main.e")  # Replace compile_file to ask_path and remove function argument
main.py
main.py. На экране.
```

Comment: у меня все работает, можно весь код?

Comment: И **полный** текст ошибки.

Comment: Весь код скинуть не могу потому что там 282 строки

Comment: @Werryx Тот пример, который Вы выложили **работает**. Можете сами в этом убедиться. Ошибка в другой части кода. Скорее всего, где-то перед циклом.

Comment: @Werryx дайте то что находится в цикле `while`

Comment: Вот весь код: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vh0HXdx81e6KnG2AY2hrBIuMych5t9XK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: main.e:
print: {5 +       7}

Comment: Попробуйте вот так объявлять переменную e = ['5+7', ]

Comment: @Paitor Нет, это вообще ничего не даст, это же не tuple. Синтаксис объявления списка из одного элемента не требует запятой.

Comment: это не к этой ошибке, конечно.. но тут "replac" не ошибка? "replace"

Comment: @Леонид Скорее всего это какая-то его собственная функция так называется

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, это моя собственная функция

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас функция `solve_num` ничего не возвращает. В конце добавьте

```
return num
```

и в функции `solve`:

```
e = solve_num(e[i])
```

поменяйте на

```
e[i] = solve_num(e[i])
```